# PHP decoding json

Tags: php, json, api, decode

could anyone here help me with php an decoding json? Im trying to decode a json api url

Here is what I have at the moment:

```
  $string = '
    {
        "username": "someusername",
        "unconfirmed_reward": "0.08681793",
        "send_threshold": "0.01000000",
        "confirmed_reward": "0.02511418",
         "workers":
        {
        "bitcoinjol.jason-laptop": {"last_share": 1307389634, "score": "0", "hashrate": 0, "shares": 0, "alive": false},
        "bitcoinjol.david-laptop": {"last_share": 1307443495, "score": "1.7742", "hashrate": 24, "shares": 1, "alive": true},
        "bitcoinjol.pierre-pc": {"last_share": 1307441804, "score": "0", "hashrate": 0, "shares": 0, "alive": true},
        "bitcoinjol.testJol": {"last_share": 0, "score": "0", "hashrate": 0, "shares": 0, "alive": false}
        },
        "wallet": "asdasdjsadajdasjdsajasjdajdajs",
        "estimated_reward": "0.00131061"
    }';

    $json_o = json_decode($string);
    echo $json_o->username;
```

and this prints out "someusername" but I cant get it to print out the workers when I try:

```
echo $json_o->workers->someusername.jason-laptop;
```

I think that the "." or the "-" I am using are invalid?

I would like to be able to print out each worker and then the waller, username and rewards ect..
using arrays or these objects, either way. I have also tried splitting the $String on "," with explode, but cant get that to work nicely either.

running Server 2008 R2 with php 5.3 and IIS 7.5

Comment: Use print_r(); on arrays or objects to display detailed information. Echo works on strings only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the curly brackets syntax suggested by [Gumbo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264598/php-decoding-json/6264646#6264646):

```
$json_o->workers->{"someusername.jason-laptop"}
```

However, the best way (imo, for consistency) is to use the resulting object as an associative array:

```
$object = json_decode($string, true);

$object['workers']['bitcoinjol.jason-laptop']['last_share']; // 1307389634
```

Answer (score 6):

The curly braces syntax should work:

```
$json_o->workers->{"someusername.jason-laptop"}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 $json_o = json_decode($string);
 print_r( $json_o->workers->{"bitcoinjol.jason-laptop"} );
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$json_o->workers['someusername.jason-laptop'];
```

Comment: `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in ...`

Comment: You need to decode the json string into an array, then it works. see json_decode() parameters.

Answer (score 1):

`-` or `.` are not valid object property names. Try instead using `json_decode($string, true)`
(the true stands for "decode as an associative array"), and then do `$json_o['workers']['someusername.jason-laptop']`.

Comment: [Gumbo has shown how it works with objects.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264598/php-decoding-json/6264646#6264646)

Comment: I do not find it a very elegant solution as "bitcoinjol.jason-laptop" is not a valid property name. It may work, but it's principally wrong.

Comment: It's not a may, it just works. So it's principally right. You might dislike to write properties in such a way, but as you can see, it's a valid property name for the json object that is available for access.

Comment: "just works" has nothing to do with "is right". For example `$foo = 1; $$foo = 'blablabla'; echo $$foo;` prints out 'blablabla' even though `$1` is NOT a valid variable name. Also, quote from the [php manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php): "Variable names follow the same rules as other labels in PHP. A valid variable name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores. As a regular expression, it would be expressed thus: '[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*'"

Comment: @cypher: $1 is not, but $$foo is. A variable is a variable and a value is a value.

Comment: Do you realize what $$foo actually does?

Comment: @cypher: Just reminding to differ between the written language and runtime. Know your language does actually mean that you should be aware about the languages features. As PHP is a scripting language it's flexible at runtime to access properties that would otherwise be reserved words or syntactical errors in code form. Therefore the variable access or curly syntax is available.