# PHP JSON decode: array with '$' problem

Tags: php, json

I have the following JSON file as input,

```
{
  "$type": "NanoWebInterpreter.WebInputData, NanoWebInterpreter",
  "NBBList": {
    "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[monoTNP.Common.NBB, monoTNP.Common]], mscorlib",
    "$values": [
      {
        "$type": "monoTNP.Common.NBB, monoTNP.Common",
        "ID": "id-0065-00000003",
        "MPList": {
          "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[monoTNP.Common.MP, monoTNP.Common]], mscorlib",
          "$values": [
            {
              "$type": "monoTNP.Common.EllipticalMP, monoTNP.Common",
              "Eccentricity": 1.0,
              "ID": "id-0065-00000006",
              "ParticleIndex": -1,
              "DispersionInteractionStrength": 0.0,
              "DispersionInteractionRange": 2.5,
              "CharacteristicSize": 0.0,
              "CenterOfMass": "<0,0,0>",
              "OrientationVector": "<>"
            },
            {
              "$type": "monoTNP.Common.CubeMP, monoTNP.Common",
              "ID": "id-0065-00000005",
              "ParticleIndex": -1,
              "DispersionInteractionStrength": 0.0,
              "DispersionInteractionRange": 2.5,
              "CharacteristicSize": 0.0,
              "CenterOfMass": "<0,0,0>",
              "OrientationVector": "<>"
            },
            {
              "$type": "monoTNP.Common.CircularMP, monoTNP.Common",
              "ID": "id-0065-00000004",
              "ParticleIndex": -1,
              "DispersionInteractionStrength": 0.0,
              "DispersionInteractionRange": 2.5,
              "CharacteristicSize": 0.0,
              "CenterOfMass": "<0,0,0>",
              "OrientationVector": "<>"
            }
          ]
        },
```

etc.

My ultimate goal is to trace this tree recursively, wrapping each key/object name with `<ul>` tags, and the properties at the "ParticleIndex" level in some kind of `<form>` structure, but I can't figure out how to index into the two '$values' arrays.

This is the code that I have been manipulating to learn how each element(object or array) is accessed:

```
foreach ($json->NBBList->'$values'[0] as $key => $value){
    var_dump($key);
    echo "\n".var_dump($value);
    echo "\n\n\n";
}
```

This obviously doesn't work because the index of values is outside of the string, but when it is on the inside, PHP interprets it as part of the string.

Is there a way for me to index into each element of the '$values' array, and ultimately in a for loop?

I'm thinking using the "true" property of JSON decode might be a better solution...

Comment: I formatted your post for you.

Comment: The json still is invalid regardless it has been formatted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264598/php-decoding-json

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access object properties with names that contain special characters using this notation:

```
$json->NBBList->{'$values'}[0]
```

I don't think that this behavior is documented anywhere, but you can find it in the [PHP grammar](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_3/Zend/zend_language_parser.y#911) (see definition of `variable_name`, which is used in `object_dim_list`, which is used in `object_property`).

Comment: For what it is worth, there is an example of this in the [`json_decode() docs`](http://uk.php.net/json_decode#example-3134).

Comment: @salathe: Ah okay. I have looked for the docs in the OOP section. Who could have thought that they've put it into the JSON documentation ^^

Comment: This question gets asked *a lot* so an example (like with SimpleXML) makes sense. :)

Answer (score 4):

Set the `assoc` parameter of [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to false to get arrays(dictionaries) instead of objects:

```
$json = json_decode($jsonInput, true);
foreach ($json['NBBList']['$values'][0] as $key => $value){
    var_dump($key);
    echo "\n";
    var_dump($value);
    echo "\n\n\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($json->NBBList->{'$values'}[0] as $key=>$value){
```

You can use curly braces around the string to access properties of an object with special characters.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried something like?

```
$show_values = $values[0];

foreach ($json->NBBList->'$show_values' as $key => $value){
var_dump($key);
echo "\n".var_dump($value);
echo "\n\n\n";
```

Just an idea, I'm not sure how well it will work

Comment: You must wrap the odd name with `{''}` even if you want to iterate over it.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, seeing the json_decode string in another post reminded me just now