# $t JSON php in a loop

Tags: php, json

From JSON I get:

```
stdClass Object ( [$t] => 2011-12-12T13:00:00.000Z )
```

How can I get this date out using PHP?

I tried:
`feed->item->'$t'` and that did not work...

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP JSON decode: array with '$' problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6310547/php-json-decode-array-with-problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$t = $feed->item->{'$t'};
```

**Beware:** 
This will only work with *single quotes*, because PHP does variable interpolation on strings with double quotes.

Comment: I also find it easier to just work with arrays `json_decode($json, true)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `{}` to get properties in that way.

```
$feed->item->{'$t'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$item = $feed->item->{$t};
```

The `{$notation}` allows you to use vars as object names.

Comment: In this case the property is literally `'$t'`.