# parsing text / json with php

Tags: php, json, parsing

```
{"email":"test@example.com","timestamp":1346345321,"newsletter":{"newsletter_user_list_id":"3648511","newsletter_id":"613267","newsletter_send_id":"657025"},"category":["EST_TEST","Newsletter"],"event":"open"}
```

I'm having trouble parsing this string. It's from Sendgrid's Event API, it seems to be "almost" JSON, but `json_decode` won't work. My goal is to get the data into an array, then into a MySQL table. I'm not asking anyone to write the code for me, just point me toward the correct method. Do I use the explode function, then `json_decode`?.
(I'm slowly teaching myself PHP, sorry if the question is not clear)

Comment: Why do you say "almost"? It seems valid according to JSONlint. Maybe there is some code or other details you might want to share?

Comment: It looks like JSON to me - have you tried plugging the result into some online json validator to be sure? Perhaps its a bug on their part if it is not returning proper json.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP decoding json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264598/php-decoding-json)

Comment: Thanks for sharing JSONlint, I will go back to coding and see if I can figure it out, I was able to use json_decode successfully on a short json string but not the above (it gave me NULL), I will try again. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're not using the json_decode function with $assoc = true, so you're getting an object rather than an array

> $json =
>   '{"email":"test@example.com","timestamp":1346345321,"newsletter":{"newsletter_user_list_id":"3648511","newsletter_id":"613267","newsletter_send_id":"657025"},"category":["EST_TEST","Newsletter"],"event":"open"}';
>
> var_dump(json_decode($json, true));

You'll get the result as array;